# How to add recursive compile definition for a target in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

Basically I have rule to create binaries for the tests source code, other rule to create binaries for the application source code. Then I have two separate rules to generate the executable for each of them (each linking to their respective libraries). Below is the sample for the rule for generating the executable for the tests. As Shown I have added a compile definition. My problem is this compile definition seems to not be passed/available recursively to the application binaries rule (when called from the rule below). So I have some code in the application that is guarded by "TESTS" and I would like that it be compiled only when this rule below is triggered. The code is also guarded in the header file.
Is there a way to achieve this?

EDIT:
To make it clearer I would like when this rule is called, this compile definition be added in the compile definition for the two targets OBJS and Tests_OBJS.

```
add_executable(tests
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:Tests_OBJS> 
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:OBJS> 
    Tests/Main.cpp) 
target_link_libraries(tests ${LIBS})
target_compile_definitions(tests PRIVATE TESTS=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Expression `$<TARGET_OBJECTS>` refers not to the sources, but to the objects. It is late for change compile definitions for the sources - they are **already compiled** at this stage. If you need set of sources to be compiled *differently* for different purposes, you need `add_library()` calls for each compilation way:

```
set(my_lib_sources ...)

# Set of objects for application
add_library(my_lib OBJECTS ${my_lib_sources})

# Set of objects for tests, they use special compile definitions
add_library(my_lib_test OBJECTS ${my_lib_sources})
target_compile_definitions(my_lib_test PRIVATE TESTS=1)

add_executable(tests
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:my_lib_test> # Already use special compile definitions
    Tests/Main.cpp)

# Uncomment, if additional definitions are needed for Tests/Main.cpp
# target_compile_definitions(tests PRIVATE TESTS=1)
```

Comment: well, that seems intuitive to have two different calls. I thought there could be something else more elegant in cmake to pass the compile definitions from a calling rule for example. but thanks anyways :)